# using one config directory for multiple application folders

Tags: php, codeigniter

this is my current directory setup.

```
application
- controllers
- models
- views
- config
- errors

public <-- document root
- images
- js
- css
```

what i want to do is set it up like this

```
frontapp
- controllers
- models
- views

membersapp
- controllers
- models
- views

adminapp
- controllers
- models
- views

config
errors
public
```

this setup would let me have all the controllers, models, and views organized for each section of the application. My question is how can i move the config and errors directories out of the application directory and allow it to be used for each application sections? The only way i see this possible is if i modified the system files but i dont want to do that because updating is going to suck. If there is a better way of doing what i am trying to accomplish let me know as well. thanks

ps: Is what im trying to do referred to as modular?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create symbolic links to your config and error folders in each of your apps:

```
ln -s config frontapp/config
ln -s config membersapp/config
ln -s config adminapp/config

ln -s errors frontapp/config
ln -s errors membersapp/config
ln -s errors adminapp/config
```

The symlink will also carry over in popular versioning systems, such as git.

This trick is also very useful for linking to different configurations files depending on environment:

```
Dev: ln -s config-dev config
Stage: ln -s config-stage config
Production: ln -s config-prod config
```

Comment: thank you for the comment, if you dont mind can you explain ln? i tried "man ln" in terminal and dont really understand how it works. Is it similar to creating an alias of a file? if that is true would i need to have that alias inside each application folder?

Comment: Yes, @SarmenB. "ln", which stands for "link", does exactly what you described: it create an "alias" to a file, or a directory. So "ln -s config frontapp/" would create an alias to "config" in your frontapp directory. Then you can access it, with "cd frontapp/config/", and its content will be the content of your original "config" directory.

Comment: thanks, i'll check it out, is this normally the right way of doing things? or is it a quick fix to things? (i might just fall in love with ln lol)

Comment: @SarmenB. This is the recommended way for reusing configuration files across multiples applications, environments, or even sharing sets of files across multiples development environments. Symlinking is one of the best tool of the developer's arsenal.

Comment: Nice!, Thank you so much, i like the idea of a config for different production levels.

Comment: also, is the setup that i am doing called modular? or is there a different name to it that you know of?

Comment: I tried the symlinks and when i load the page i get errors that the constants.php file inside the config cannot be found. Did i do something wrong?

Comment: @SarmenB. that means your symlink is improperly created.

Comment: i typed what you wrote, is there anything else i need?